# How do I add a related tags list to a wordpress tag page

Tags: tags

I would like a tag list that shows related tags on a tag page.

For example when on the tag page for the tag "Technology", I would like a tag list of other popular related to that tag based on other posts that share those tagas and the "technology" tag i.e tags like "Apple, Android, PC" etc.

I imagine this will be done by pulling the tags from the latest posts in that  category then ranking them based on usage and then generating a list from the most popular.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't the most helpful answer, but here is the plugin I have used which attempts to do that: [Related Topics Simple Tag List](https://wordpress.org/plugins/related-topics-simple-tag-list/).